# Send a GET request with a body using Fuel

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I need to send a body with a GET request but got: `"Exception : lateinit property sourceCallback has not been initialized".` I'm using Fuel in **kotlin 1.3.10** with ***Android Studio***.

Is there an alternative or something ?

I follow you my function,

```
private fun getReq (json : JSONObject) {

    thread {
        FuelManager.instance.basePath = "https://blih.epitech.eu"
        Fuel.upload("/repositories", Method.GET)
            .body(json.toString().toByteArray())
            .header("Content-Type" to "application/json")
            .response { request, response, result ->
                val (bytes, error) = result
                if (bytes != null) {
                    println("[response bytes] ${String(bytes)}")
                }
                println(error)
            }
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

Update:

I add `.source { _, _ -> File.createTempFile("temp", ".tmp")}` and no longer have a problem with sourceCallback but now got "Exception : method does not support a request body: GET". Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dev of the Fuel lib answer me it'll be added on the version 2.0.0

[github answer from Fuel dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcDEG.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/issues/529), you need a `.dataParts` when using `upload`:

> .upload requests are application/form-multipart, which always require
>   DataPart at the moment